# The number of nodes in a binary tree

Tags: binary-trees, heaps

If a binary tree is both a max-heap and an AVL tree, what is its largest possible number of nodes, assuming all keys are different?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual questions but just answering homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say 2.

A max-heap is a near-complete binary tree. This means any child must have a key less than it's parent's key.

An AVL tree is a balanced binary **search** tree. This means the left child must have a key less than it's parent and the right child must have key greater than it's parent.

From these, You can see that there can be no right-children in the tree. Hence, You can only have left-children. Since the max-heap has the near-complete property, The largest tree you can have is the root node with a left-child.

Hence, The maximum size is 2.